# PgAdmin Function return type

Tags: sql, function, pgadmin

I am creating a stored procedure in PgAdmin to insert data into a table from different tables. I have tried the following code but I am being asked for a return type. What do I need to add?

Also, how do I use this procedure to insert the data into the table from different tables?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stager.ProductDimSP 
(
cat_name character varying(25)  ,
pr_name character varying(40) ,
pr_id character varying(6)  ,
disc boolean      
) RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT AS
$$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO stager."ProductDimTable"
  ( 
    category_name, product_name, product_id, discontinued           
  ) 
 VALUES 
  ( 
   cat_name, pr_name, pr_id, disc
  ) 
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: When I add RETURNS void before the END, I still get an ERROR:  function result type must be specified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stager.ProductDimSP 
(
 cat_name character varying(25)  ,
 pr_name character varying(40) ,
 pr_id character varying(6)  ,
 disc boolean      
) 
RETURNS VOID -- this defines a function with no return value
AS
$$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO stager."ProductDimTable"
  ( 
    category_name, product_name, product_id, discontinued           
  ) 
 VALUES 
  ( 
   cat_name, pr_name, pr_id, disc
  ); -- this semicolon was also missing
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;  -- do not put the language name in quotes
```

Comment: thank you :) Now I need to use the function to populate the table with fields from two different tables. How can I do this? I am trying this but I doubt it is correct as I get errors: SELECT stager."ProductDimSP"("Category".category_name, "Products".product_name, 
"Products".product_id, "Products".discontinued)